# How can I restrict which user can delete items in Amazon SimpleDB?

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'd like to use Amazon SimpleDB to store data for my iPhone app. Different users will own items within the same domain. I'd like for users to be able to delete their own items but not each others', and for this restriction to be enforced server-side.

I am hoping to use anonymous TVM.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using IAM User Management you can create a custom policy for each user or group to allow or deny access to delete items in SimpleDB. If each user has their own domain you can restrict access to the domain by using the arn format `arn:aws:sdb:<region>:<account_ID>:domain/<domain_name>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't use IAM - you seem to say that you have one domain where all user data is stored.

One way to achieve what you want is to use item name prefixes that are user based, e.g. user jimsmith would have all items stored under an item name that beings with 'jimsmith' or some random string, unique to jimsmith (which could be stored somewhere).

Then you are in charge of security, so you would not be able to have the phones directly query AWS - they would need to talk to your intermediary server which would handle security. You have to assume that people could run the app on a jailbroken phone, and decompile, etc.

You can use IAM to restrict a single user to a small portion of an S3 bucket though. You could then index the bucket using a server app of your design. Then the DB could be used for searching purposes with your own code, so that iPhones only deal with S3.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have researched the simpleDB user right policies aren't designed to be used in such a way you are proposing (meaning undisclosed number of users of the app) and the way to handle this might be to use some server application in-the-middle as was suggested here: [Mobile app and SimpleDB direct 'Access Policy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528670/mobile-app-and-simpledb-direct-access-policy)